# Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints Pr@blem Marker - > Generate App Engine Error on clean Android Project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine

I created a clean Android Application `A` then I right clicked on it and selected `Google->Generate App Engine` That caused this:

[image]

and the error description is that:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes: com.google.api.server.spi.tools.ClientLibGenerator$Language   A-AppEngine     Unknown Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints Problem Marker
```

**How to fix this?**

Comment: Have you tried restarting your computer?

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu No I will do it now.

Comment: @OjonugwaOchalifu No change at all after restart.

Comment: I don't really know what's wrong.But most times when i get this sort of error, i delete the project, restart my computer and try again and it works.Just be patient,am sure someone who knows will come along.

Comment: Im having the same problem, and the accepted solution did remove the error but the build operation was really short. Also, a consequent clean operation shows this error again. Did you find any other solution ?

Comment: @AsafK Yeah, download App Engine 1.93, new one does not work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After checking out a lot of posts I finally fixed this error, though I have no clue why it is happening:

- Right click on the project
- Properties-->Builders
- Uncheck the Google App Engine Project Validator.
- Then clean the project.
- Then check the Google App Engine Project Validator again.
- Then left click the project,
- Go to Project-->Build Project.
- Done.

Anyone can explain this?

Answer (score 0):

The true answer is: Download older App Engine 1.93 even if you should 1.94.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem a while back with an android app and the accepted solution worked.

Right now I have the same problem with a GWT/GAE app. (GAE 1.9.9)

The only way I can stop it is revert to a backup. On replacing the (irrelelevant) code changes the problem has not so far not reappeared.