# An error occured when Generate Cloud Endpoint Library on clean project

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, endpoint

I have created `Google App Engine` for a clean Android Application like show here:
[Google App Engine Cloud Endpoints Pr@blem Marker - > Generate App Engine Error on clean Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595180/generate-app-engine-error-on-clean-android-project)

I added an Entity:

```
package com.example.smbp1;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.jdo.annotations.PersistenceCapable;

@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    int id;
    String name;
    double price;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


}
```

and generated endpoint to it.

Then when I click on a Backend engine application `right-click -> Google-> Generate Cloud Endpoint Library`

I get this:

[image]

but there are no errors visible in Eclipse:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can display the errors using `Window -> Show View -> Error Log`, the `Problems` tab does not log them.

As for the Endpoint generation - are you using Google Plugin for Eclipse 3.5.1 and Google App Engine SDK 1.9.4? Which means the newest version? If so, [there is a known bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-plugin-for-eclipse/issues/detail?id=278). Install GAE 1.9.3 manually, it should work. [Follow this instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23595823).