# Eclipse Java Web app generating following error - "Generating the api metadata for your cloud endpoints classes"

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, cloud, google-cloud-endpoints

When I try to create a new web app, eclipse automatically gives the error below:

"There was a problem generating the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes: unknown protocol: c"

I searched on many places but I couldn't find an effective solution.

I changed the SDK version 3 times. I tried 1.9.17 - 1.9.15 - 1.9.13 - 1.9.3 but always results in the same error.

Comment: Making your question stand out by capsing the title is...not a good idea. You will not attract the kind of attention you want

Comment: In my opinion here is a help place not trying find faults of people. I hope you have an answer about my problem too!

Answer (score 2):

Solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595180/google-app-engine-cloud-endpoints-prblem-marker-generate-app-engine-error-o)

- Right click on the project
- Properties-->Builders
- Uncheck the Google App Engine Project Validator.
- Then clean the project.
- Then check the Google App Engine Project Validator again.
- Then left click the project,
- Go to Project-->Build Project.

If it still doesn't work for you try with old versions of App Engine like 1.9.3 and older.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I read and tried your link actually but i didnt solve yesterday. Forewer now It provides a solution for current project but all new projects come with same error. Do you have any idea about all?

Comment: @VIPER Currently I'm using Android Studio which have good integration with GAE and GCE. I had this problem a long ago while using Eclipse and the solution worked well. Maybe it's time switch to Android Studio if you're developing also for Android?

Comment: Thanks for advice now im working on JAVA for desktop app but i will work on Android, that time i can use Android Studio thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem becouse It was an error in my *.gwt.xml.
There was a wrong path in

```
<set-configuration-property name="gin.ginjector"
       value="com.gwtplatform.samples.basic.client.MyGinjector" />
```

My MyGinjector has another location.
When it was fixed, all was good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path of the project workspace, eclipse install folder and Google App Engine folder does not contain any spaces.

I think the "c" at the end of the error refers to the Windows "C"-drive.